# ASPNET Core MVC ajax not passing data correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Goal: I'm setting up the checkout page for my website and would like to have the user select from a list of their addresses. When they select it, it will add it to the cache and save it for when they have everything set up and are ready to complete their order.

Issue: When selecting the address, and pressing save changes, it returns 0 instead of the actual value of the item and I don't know why.

Here's the form:

[image: Form]

Here's the view:

[image: View]

```
@model AirmotionEcommerceWebsite.Models.Home.CheckoutModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Checkout";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br />
<div class="container">
    <h1>Checkout</h1>

    <form>
        <div class="jumbotron row product-container">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @{
                    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dataItems = ViewBag.UserAddresses;
                }

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4>To Address:</h4>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedShippingAddress.IntShippingAddressId, dataItems, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedShippingAddress.IntShippingAddressId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddShippingAddress">Add New Address</a>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ajax-method="get" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#ValidateAddress"
                            data-url="@Url.Action("CheckoutChanges", new { intShippingAddressID = Model.selectedShippingAddress.IntShippingAddressId })">Verify Address</button>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </form>

</div>


<script>
    $(function () {
        $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            // get the form containing the submit button
            var form = $(this).closest('form')
            // serialize all the fields in the form
            var model = form.serialize();
            // the the request to the url along with the form (model) data
            $.get(url, model).done(function (data) {
                PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Here's the controllers:
[image]

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult Checkout()
        {
            // get userid
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            // get addresses for this user
            ViewBag.UserAddresses = GetShippingAddresses(userId);

            CheckoutModel model = new CheckoutModel();
            model.selectedShippingAddress = new TwebShippingAddress();

            bool AlreadyExists = memoryCache.TryGetValue<CheckoutModel>("CachedModel", out model);
            if (!AlreadyExists)
            {
                model = new CheckoutModel();
                model.selectedShippingAddress = new TwebShippingAddress();
                var cachEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
                memoryCache.Set("CachedModel", model, cachEntryOptions);
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CheckoutChanges(int intShippingAddressID)
        {
            if (intShippingAddressID == 0)
                return View();
            CheckoutModel model = new CheckoutModel();

            bool AlreadyExists = memoryCache.TryGetValue<CheckoutModel>("CachedModel", out model);

            if (AlreadyExists)
            {
                model.selectedShippingAddress = context.TwebShippingAddresses.Where(x => x.IntShippingAddressId == model.selectedShippingAddress.IntShippingAddressId).FirstOrDefault();
                var cachEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
                memoryCache.Set("CachedModel", model, cachEntryOptions);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Lastly, this is the GetShippingAddresses() method:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetShippingAddresses(string strUserID)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var cat = context.TwebShippingAddresses.Include(x => x.IntState).Where(x => x.IntWebUserId == strUserID).OrderByDescending(x=>x.BlnIsDefault);

            foreach (var item in cat)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.IntShippingAddressId.ToString(), Text = item.StrName + " " + item.StrAttnTo + " " + item.StrStreet1 + " " + item.StrStreet2 + ", " + item.StrCity + " " + item.IntState.StrStateCode + " " + item.StrZip  });
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: Because you've "baked-in" the id when the page was generated server-side `data-url="@Url.Action("CheckoutChanges", new { intShippingAddressID =...})"`.

Comment: So what should I replace it with?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `$.get` like this to pass a Json object that will be auto binded to the action's parameter:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            // get the form containing the submit button
            var form = $(this).closest('form')
            // serialize all the fields in the form
            var model = form.serialize();
            // the the request to the url along with the form (model) data
            
            int selectedIndex = //Write jquery code to get the selected index here
            
            
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                data: { intShippingAddressID: selectedIndex },
                dataType: 'json',
            })
            .success(function( data ) {         
                PlaceHolderElement.html(data);          
        });
        
        })
    })
</script>
```

Note the Json data type and the property that match the parameter of the Action.